# Enemy chase limit C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been struggling with something for some time now, I was
wondering how do I limit how many enemies can chase the player at once? I want to limit it to 3 enemies. I would really appreciate if anyone can figure this out for me.

Here is my code:

```
 private void ChasePlayer()
 {
    enemyAmount++;
    enemyChasing = true;
    if (enemyAmount <= 3 && enemyChasing == true) { return; }
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position)
        <= followRadius && Vector2.Distance
        (target.position, transform.position) > attackRadius
        && CurrentState != EnemyState.stagger)
        {
            Vector3 temp = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Animator(temp - transform.position);
            myRigidbody.MovePosition(temp);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else if (enemyAmount > 3)
        {
            enemyChasing = false;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
        else if (Vector2.Distance(target.position,
        transform.position) > followRadius)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could track the number of enemies currently chasing the player. Maybe using a static integer. And if the number exceeds your required limit, return at the beginning of the function which makes the enemies chase the player.

Comment: Hasnain how would I go about that? sorry I am still newish to programming

Comment: There should be a 
    public static int NumberOfEnemiesCurrentlyChasingPlayer = 0;
Ideally in your AI script.

Then in the function that is called when AI decides to chase player you should increment this variable. e.g:

void ChasePlayer(){
NumberOfEnemiesCurrentlyChasingPlayer++;

if(NumberOfEnemiesCurrentlyChasingPlayer > 3)
return;

//your rest of playerChase logic
}

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your comment.. but I can't seem to get it to work.. so I tried to add a enemy chasing bool.. and still had no luck. I updated the post with my current code.

Comment: You're returning when the number is less than equal to 3. 
    if (enemyAmount <= 3 && enemyChasing == true) return;

I think you want the opposite.
And let me see your enemyAmount variable declaration.

Comment: When I do the opposite then the enemies don't even start chasing the player.. and the enemyAmount is public static int enemyAmount = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
You need to have a separate if for the return statement.
Currently, your lower block is running in all cases.

```
 private void ChasePlayer()
 {
    enemyAmount++;
    enemyChasing = true;
    if (enemyAmount > 3 && enemyChasing == true) {return;}
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position) 
        <= followRadius && Vector2.Distance
        (target.position, transform.position) > attackRadius
        && CurrentState != EnemyState.stagger)
        {
            Vector3 temp = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
            target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            Animator(temp - transform.position);
            myRigidbody.MovePosition(temp);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else if (enemyAmount > 3)
        {
            enemyChasing = false;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }          
        else if (Vector2.Distance(target.position, 
        transform.position) > followRadius && enemyAmount >= 4)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you suggested to remove else block in edit btw?

Comment: Else block? sorry I don't even know what that is.. I only know what else if is

Comment: if(){ // if block}
else{ // else block}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start using PlayerPrefs. [Read about it here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)
Try using it. It works on almost all platforms and I use it in nearly all of my projects.

```
private void ChasePlayer()
{
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("enemyAmount")<3)
{PlayerPrefs.SetInt("enemyAmount",enemyAmount);
enemyAmount++;
enemyChasing = true;
if (enemyAmount <= 3 && enemyChasing == true) { return; }
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(target.position, transform.position)
    <= followRadius && Vector2.Distance
    (target.position, transform.position) > attackRadius
    && CurrentState != EnemyState.stagger)
    {
        Vector3 temp = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
        target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Animator(temp - transform.position);
        myRigidbody.MovePosition(temp);
        animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
    }
    else if (enemyAmount > 3)
    {
        enemyChasing = false;
        animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
    }
    else if (Vector2.Distance(target.position,
    transform.position) > followRadius)
    {
        animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
    }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Hello.. this a cool idea, I use PlayerPrefs for saving.. but for some reason using PlayerPrefs for this stops the enemies from following the player

Comment: I know right. I don't know if I could live without Playerprefs.